# How to implement a reminder application?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, reminders

I know that the reminder application should display a badge or sound or kind of alert to the user .

The only doubt I want to clear from you guys is , should I display the badge in some manual coding fashion (like `[[uiapplication sharedApplication] setBadgeNumber:2]`) or I have to use Apple push notification service and push the notification from a provider server?

I just want to know to implement the reminder application in correct way . Also any links to tutorials or examples would be appreciable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the reminder is to be triggered?

If you just need to set it for when the app is running, do it in code, and then when the app is quit, the badge number will be visible on the app's icon.

If you need to push a remind to the phone while the app isn't running then you'll need to use the push notification service.

Comment: Thank you very much , But can you redirect me to any good link or tutorial of implementing the APNs because in my app I have to do it in both way .

Comment: And also if I want to show badges on my custom buttons or icons then how can I do so ?

Comment: If you mean setting badges on buttons and icon within your app (not on home screen), then you'd have to implement your own custom view that looks the same as a badge, and add it as a subview to your button / icon.